# Is there a way to generate the bundledDependencies list automatically?

Tags: node.js, npm, nodejitsu

I have an app that I'm deploying to Nodejitsu. Recently, they suffered from npm issues that caused my app to go offline for several hours after I tried (and failed) to restart it, as its dependencies could not be installed. I was told that this could be averted in the future by listing all of my dependencies as `bundledDependencies` in my package.json, causing the dependencies to be uploaded along with the rest of the application. Which means that I need my package.json to look something like this:

```
"dependencies": {
  "express": "2.5.8",
  "mongoose": "2.5.9",
  "stylus": "0.24.0"
},
"bundledDependencies": [
  "express",
  "mongoose",
  "stylus"
]
```

Now, on DRY grounds, this is unappealing. But what's worse is the maintenance: Every time I add or remove a dependency, I have to make the change in two places. Is there a command I can use to sync `bundledDependencies` with `dependencies`?

Comment: PING :)  Did this answer your question or is there something else to be solved?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about implementing a [grunt.js](http://gruntjs.com) task to do it?  This works:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.registerTask('bundle', 'A task that bundles all dependencies.', function () {
    // "package" is a reserved word so it's abbreviated to "pkg"
    var pkg = grunt.file.readJSON('./package.json');
    // set the bundled dependencies to the keys of the dependencies property
    pkg.bundledDependencies = Object.keys(pkg.dependencies);
    // write back to package.json and indent with two spaces
    grunt.file.write('./package.json', JSON.stringify(pkg, undefined, '  '));
  });

};
```

Put that in the root directory of your project in a file called `grunt.js`.  To install grunt, use npm: `npm install -g grunt`.  Then bundle the packages by executing `grunt bundle`.

A commentor mentioned an npm module that could be useful: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-bundled-dependencies (I haven't tried it.)

Comment: took your answer and made a library.. https://github.com/GuyMograbi/grunt-bundled-dependencies. please consider adding to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple Node.js script to read and update the `bundleDependencies` property and run it via npm lifecycle hooks/scripts.

My folder structure is:

- `scripts/update-bundle-dependencies.js`
- `package.json`

`scripts/update-bundle-dependencies.js`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');    
const pkgPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "../package.json");
const pkg = require(pkgPath);
pkg.bundleDependencies = Object.keys(pkg.dependencies);    
const newPkgContents = JSON.stringify(pkg, null, 2);    
fs.writeFileSync(pkgPath, newPkgContents);
console.log("Updated bundleDependencies");
```

If you are using the latest version of `npm` (> 4.0.0), you can use the `prepublishOnly` or `prepack` script: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts

> prepublishOnly: Run BEFORE the package is prepared and packed, ONLY on
>   npm publish. (See below.)
>
> prepack: run BEFORE a tarball is packed (on npm pack, npm publish, and
>   when installing git dependencies)

`package.json`:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "prepack": "npm run update-bundle-dependencies",
    "update-bundle-dependencies": "node scripts/update-bundle-dependencies"
  }
}
```

You can test it yourself by running `npm run update-bundle-dependencies`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: isn't it `bundledDependencies` instead of 
`pkg.bundleDependencies = Object.keys(pkg.dependencies);`